# umask and exit functions

Tags: posix, d

I am writing a function to convert a D application to a daemon. I am planning to share it (I don't know where though. Is there any where, so maybe it gets into Phobos. Anyway)

Everything works great. I am using core.sys.posix.unistd for fork. But I couldn't have found any declaration of "umask" C function. I searched for all files for this function name in Phobos folder, but none of files has it as function name. Anyone knows maybe an equivalent?

And another thing is the exit function. While I am reading "The D Programming Language" book, it said to use "assert(false)", but I think there must be another, more handsome function for this?

Comment: perhaps because it is posix specific?

Comment: There is already a posix folder in Phobos. If it is posix specific, it should be there then. `unistd.d` example has lots of posix functions in it already. In C, `umask` is defined in `stat.h`, but there is no file with name `stat.h` unfortunately in Phobos directory.

Comment: I have found the function `exit` in `std.c.process` and `_exit` in `core.sys.posix.unistd`. But I am still looking for `umask`.

Comment: Okay. I have exported umask from C. Everything is okay now. It works perfectly.

Comment: It should be in this file: https://github.com/D-Programming-Language/druntime/blob/master/src/core/sys/posix/sys/stat.d .You could open a pull request on github to add that declaration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
core/sys/posix/sys/stat.d:mode_t umask(mode_t);
```

Comment: Thanks Andrei. It was night time. I missed this file it looks like.